# Google Drive API with Laravel 5.4 / jQuery / AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, google-drive-api, laravel-5.4

I try to use Google Drive API on my Laravel 5.4 project. After a lot of research and many hours of testing, my code always give me a 500 internal server error.

Here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5fff93d20fe15869625d1f3cfa3a23e

Could someone help me please? (Thanks)

If you need more information, please just ask me.

Here is the log file:

```
[2018-02-20 15:12:33] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found in D:\mywebsite\app\Http\Controllers\GoogleDriveApiController.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\GoogleDriveApiController->getApi()
#1 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('getApi', Array)
#3 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\GoogleDriveApiController), 'getApiGD')
#4 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#5 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(574): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#6 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 D:\mywebsite\app\Http\Middleware\Language.php(31): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\Language->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(576): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#30 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(535): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(513): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 D:\mywebsite\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 D:\mywebsite\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\mywebsite...')
#51 {main}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `Storage::disk("google")->cloud()->listContent($dir, $recursive)`

Comment: I just tried it and nothing changes.

Comment: does your laravel.log has some usefull logs on the error 500?

Comment: @SérgioReis I had my log on my main post.

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Storage` at start of the controller

Since laravel works with namespaces, when you need to access one laravel [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades) you need to say in your controller you want to have access to that facade https://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/

Comment: Thanks! I add it, but I have another error:  local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found

Comment: I am not using S3, I am using google... Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: Yes... I always have a 500 error. But here is a new error on my log file: InvalidArgumentException: Driver [] is not supported. in D:\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php:124

Comment: On your filesystems.php, search for `'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3')` if it exists, change it to 
`    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 'google'),` and in your .env change FILESYSTEM_CLOUD to 'google'

Comment: I already did it... .env: FILESYSTEM_CLOUD=google and filesystems.php: 'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 'google'),